# ios sync socket option

Tags: ios, sockets, tcp

I am working on an ios application to connect to a server using TCP and display the received bytes to the screen.
I followed many example out there internet using NSStream(async) and I do connect and get some byte.
Problem is async socket may merge multiple TCP packet into one event trigger (standard behavior). The server's reply byte length is various, async socket seem cannot help to chop the packet correctly.

I wonder if sync socket will solve this problem, and here are the question:

1. Will sync socket merge packets as mentioned above?
2. Except from POSIX (as many article tell me not to use POSIX), what are the other option of sync socket on IOS?
3. Any example code I can follow?

Answer (score 0):

The use of synchronous calls will not really solve your problem.  Essentially a TCP session is just a stream of bytes.  The underlying network stacks and devices have no requirement to maintain transmission groupings.  Even if you use synchronous/blocking calls you may still end up with multiple 'transmissions' returned to your code from a read request.

You need to write your code so that it can detect the discrete messages contained in the streams.  This is typically done with a header that contains the length of the message or, in simple cases, a terminating character (such as a carriage return)

Comment: I am new to objectC(ios) but I never get this issue in java/C. As the content on the server site is already fixed(no header/termination char as it is bytes data) and I am not the only client using the server. Any work around you may suggest? Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like your protocol is "broken".  It is flawed to rely on TCP transmissions as a delimiter. You can do this with UDP because each packet is discreet

Comment: What if the server's reply is in a low frequency.(say 5 second per packet). Problem now is hasBytesAvailable didn't triggler and after 10 seconds I got two packet in one read.

Comment: Exactly.  The protocol is relying on behaviour that isn't defined for a TCP stream.  It was only a matter of time until it broke on a particular implementation of a TCP/IP stack and now it has.

Comment: Even we are talking that I should not rely on TCP packet as delimiter. This is very poor in term of performance. Do I have control over how the hasBytesAvailable to trigger? Else will sync socket help?

Comment: Actually it may be better in terms of performance - on a battery powered device it is better for battery life to wake the radio less frequently and transfer larger amounts of data.  I doubt that synchronous calls will help.  You could try a more sophisticated library, such as GCDAsyncSocket -http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/CocoaAsyncSocket/7.0.3/Classes/GCDAsyncSocket.html

Comment: By performance I mean how real time the server client communication is. There are big delay. What you see the different between syncSocket and asyncsocket?

Answer (score 0):

At the end, I solved the problem using POSIX socket in C. Thanks.